# Excel formula to get last entry in a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet where each row begins with a string identifier, followed by a series of values for each week since the sheet was created:

```
XXX    15    20    25
YYY    11    15    19
ZZZ    18    22    22
```

On another sheet I would like to have some of the string identifiers from the first page (not all), and only the latest value for that item:

```
XXX    25
ZZZ    22
```

I actually want multiple sheets of the second kind, with each string id possible appearing on more than one sheet.

I can't use VBA as this has to be viewed (and values added and altered) on my Windows Phone 7 (I do not believe the mobile version of excel supports VBA, but correct me if I'm wrong). Is there a formula that's able to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the last non-blank cell in ROW range

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:M1<>""),A1:M1)
```

1. on your master sheet you should designate a hidden column like ZZ to contain the formula: `=LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:ZY1<>""),A1:ZY1)` this will put in column ZZ all the LAST values of that specific row
2. on all of the other sheets that depend on your master, you can use a vlookup to retrieve the information in ZZ from the master sheet

Comment: If you just want the last `number` in A1:ZY1 it's sufficient to use =LOOKUP(10^100,A1:ZY1)