# calc/excel: retreive last value of a row after finding value in column

Tags: search, excel-formula, libreoffice-calc

I have a calc spreedsheet, which is mostly similar to excel regarding formulas. In one sheet I have the details of some boughts I've done (`comprasDet`) and in another the items I can buy (`productos`).
The first entry in `comprasDet` looks like this:

[image: comprasDet sheet]

I need to retreive from `productos` the last registered cost from "Shampo y Mascarilla Chocolate....", put it in ctUnit (that stands for unitary cost) and then calculate the entry cost in ctTot.
The last registered costs in the `productos` sheet are:

[image: productos sheet]
In this case, I need the value in the `F12` cell - $6.00. Now, I know that with:

```
MATCH(D2,$productos.D:D,0) (written in comprasDet)
```

I can get the row number of "Shampo y Mascarilla Chocolate..." in `productos` (12), and with (formula taken from this [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713615/excel-formula-to-get-last-entry-in-a-row)):

```
LOOKUP(2,1/($productos.12:12<>""),$productos.12:12)
```

I get actually the last value in the 12th row ($6.00) - the thing is, I need to be able to look for the last price for any given value in `comprasDet`, for example, if instead of "Shampo y Mascarilla Chocolate..." I have "Keratina Brasileña (1 lt)" I'll would like to get the `F4` value in `productos` ($7.00).
The sheet `productos` will be getting more columns as the prices vary, for example, in the previos print, there were only two price columns (ct20210918 and ct20211001), here is an example with another price modification:

[image: productos sheet]

And, in this scenario, the price I need to get from "Shampo y Mascarilla Chocolate..." with a formula inside the `comprasDet` sheet will be the value in `productos` in cell G12, $8.00.

Note: I know that in excel the notation to reference cell/s in another sheet is `Sheet_name!First_cell:Last_cell`, in libreoffice calc changes a little, `Sheet_name.First_cell:Last_cell`, but the formulas are pretty much the same.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: With the new requirements, you need to use `COLUMN` and `MAX` to find the last used column. Because you are looking for the last used column of a particular row, you need to use `INDIRECT` to reference only that row. Here is how you do it in excel. You will have to modify it for your program

```
=INDEX(productos!A:AD,MATCH(D2,productos!D:D,0),MAX(COLUMN(INDIRECT("R"&MATCH(D2,productos!D:D,0)&"C1:"&"R"&MATCH(D2,productos!D:D,0)&"C30"))))
```

Explanation:
`MATCH(D2,productos!D:D,0)` gets the correct row in the productos table. I'll call it `MyRow`.

`INDIRECT("R"&MyRow&"C1:"&"R"&MyRow&"C30")` creates a reference to the first 30 columns of `MyRow`. I'll call it `MyRange`. Note, "30" is an arbitrary number. Make it large enough that you always get the data.

`COLUMN(MyRange)` creates an array of column indexes for all filled cells in `MyRange`.

`MAX(COLUMN(MyRange))` gets the largest column index, which is the last filled cell. I'll call this `MyCol`.

`=INDEX(productos!A:AD,MyRow,MyCol)' returns the last used column of the row you are interested in.

Original Answer:
If this was excel you would use `XLOOKUP`.

```
=XLOOKUP(D2,'productos'!D:D,'productos'!F:F,"-",0,-1)
```

If your program has access to the index function, this should work:

```
=INDEX($productos.F:F, MATCH(D2,$productos.D:D,0))
```

Comment: Thanks @Dave, CALC don't use XLOOKUP, and the main problem is that I need to write the formula in one sheet to look for the value in another, and the number of columns to search in the 2nd will be increasing - I modified the question in order to explain this.

Comment: @Gerardo, See my edit. Hope this helps.